# SharpDX. Сохранить DeviceContext.Target в Image

Tags: c#, изображения, directx, sharpdx

Как скопировать содержимое `DeviceContext.Target` в `Image`?
Мне необходимо замерить время копирование данных в `Image`. Затем вызвать функцию `WriteFrame` с этим `Image`.
Вот часть кода. Как сделать именно копирование данных? Судя по времени, происходит копирование ссылки, а не данных.

```
    using d2 = SharpDX.Direct2D1;  
    private List<d2.DeviceContext> dvContext;
    ...
    Stopwatch _stwp = new Stopwatch();
     _stwp.Start();
    // copy to Image
     d2.Image img = dvContext[writeFromContext].Target;
     _stwp.Stop();
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("To Image " +_stwp.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
     _stwp.Restart();
     // save to file
     imageEncoder.WriteFrame(img, bitmapFrameEncode, new wic.ImageParameters(d2PixelFormat, 96, 96, 0, 0, outputImageSize.Width, outputImageSize.Height));
    _stwp.Stop();
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("WriteFrame " + _stwp.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

При приравнивании ссылочных типов, копируется только ссылка. Эт факт.
Для копирования всего объекта используется метод: `Clone()`.
Не уверен что конкретно в данном случае он будет работать (не работал с этой библиотекой), но по идее должно выглядеть так:

```
 d2.Image img = dvContext[writeFromContext].Target.Clone();
```